# Find BLAS giving the path to the lib

Tags: cmake, lapack, blas

I use blas/lapack in my C++ code built with CMake 2.8.9. I want to find BLAS and LAPACK libraries with the CMake commands :

```
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
```

But it can found it because the libraries are in a specific directory. The error is the following :

```
CMake Error at /softs/cmake/2.8.9/64/gcc/4.7.2/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:594 (message):
A required library with BLAS API not found.  Please specify library
```

**My question :** How can I specify an additional path to help FindBLAS to work, in the same way I do it for Boost (see below) ?

```
set(PATH_BOOST "/softs/boost/1.53.0/${ARCH}/${COMPILER_NAME}/${COMPILER_VERSION}")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "${PATH_BOOST}/include")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "${PATH_BOOST}/lib")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost 1.53.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for is `BLAS_DIR` and `LAPACK_DIR` variable.

```
set(BLAS_DIR /path/to/blas)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
set(LAPACK_DIR /path/to/lapack)
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
```